# og:image reads the image url but does not show the thumbnail

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-like

I have added a like button using iFrame for the site and added the og meta tags. while viewing in Facebook debug tool it does not show any errors and shows all the meta data from the website. But the thumpnail preview is not getting displayed.
[see the Facebook debug output](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://www.pachi-cam.jp/artist/profile.php?artist_id=140)

- When I click on the thumbnail link, it takes to the right image and displayed correctly. * The domain is simply an NON secure domain.
- The image I am using 100X75

http://graph.facebook.com/10150536591853797

The following meta tags has been included in the file.

```
<meta property="og:site_name" content="パチカメ" />
<meta property="og:locale" content="ja_JP" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="297487356974821" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.pachi-cam.jp/artist/profile.php?artist_id=140" />
<meta property="og:title" content="Dr.ゆに さんのギャラリー" />
<meta property="og:description" content="こんにちわ " />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.pachi-cam.jp/upload/files/140/23203/thumb_S_phpapCLQi.jpg" />
```

iFrame code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http://www.pachi-cam.jp/artist/profile.php?artist_id=141&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=true&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=80" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:80px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [og:image ignored when sharing link, although accepted in linter](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9213912/ogimage-ignored-when-sharing-link-although-accepted-in-linter/9214720#9214720) - it may not have been that poster's issue but it has been the most common reason I've seen for `og:image`s not embeddeding correctly

{edit}
looks like your server is rejecting the request:

```
curl -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" -i 'http://www.pachi-cam.jp/upload/files/140/23203/thumb_S_phpapCLQi.jpg'

HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Date: Mon, 13 Feb 2012 09:13:59 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (EL)
Content-Length: 324
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
```

Comment: edited answer there, i can see why it isn't working in your case (for me, at least)

Answer (score 1):

You might be confusing Facebook by having id=140 in your meta tags, but id=141 in your iframe code.

Comment: DMCS thanks for the reply.Tried changing the id, but still does not show the thumbnail.